# Try catch block not working in wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, try-catch

I have a WCF service that has been running for a long time now. I recently made some changes and it works fine locally but crashes with this message server side (only for the method that I changed, all other methods work fine)

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

The problem is I have no way to debug the problem as it is only failing on the server. More frustrating, I know exactly where the code is failing I just can't tell why because I can never pull the exception data. Here is the method that is being hit in the WCF service.

```
    public bool GenerateSpec(string product)
    {
        specService.GenerateSpec(product);
        return true;
    }
```

Which then calls this.

```
    public bool GenerateSpec(string productNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            SessionFactory factory = new SessionFactory();
            Session = factory.CreateSession(DataConnection.PM);
            productService = new ProductService(Session);

            // other code
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            emailService.SendMessage(e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I know it fails at the `Session = factory.CreateSession(DataConnection.PM);` line but don't know why and it seems to just be ignoring my try catch block and dying anyways. What could be going on?

Comment: This looks like it cannot find the method. Use Fiddler to see what it the call returns.

Comment: You can set your Web.Config so that server-side exception details are returned to the client, so you can see the real exception.  In your serviceBehavior, try setting <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />

Comment: Sounds like the SendMessage call is throwing an exception.

Comment: @Jim your comment was what helped me figure it out. It was a simple issue. Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You renamed productNumber. Did you update the client proxy?

Comment: Attach the debugger to the service and single-step through. Set it to halt on all exceptions. Don't just watch the symptoms, investigate and look inside!

Comment: FYI, you're better off using `e.ToString()` rather than combining `e.Message` and `e.StackTrace`. There's often much more information in the exception than you're displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your Web.Config so that server-side exception details are returned to the client, so you can see the real exception.

In your serviceBehavior, try setting

`<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the line:

```
emailService.SendMessage(e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);
```

Is not throwing an exception on the server?  It could be reaching your try catch block but throwing another exception on this line.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was the issue as well. However, I went ahead and commented that out and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it cannot find the method. Use Fiddler to see what the call returns.